# Video view in android buffering very slow

Tags: android, android-videoview

Videoview in android is taking long time in buffering a high quality video and sometimes its hanging up with progressbar and does not play.

This happens with video recorded from the built-in camera .

Any solution for this ??

Comment: Show your code and logcat for when it hangs.

Comment: no errors in logcat but this keeps on showing the progress dialogue , very slowing ....